# Writing object fields with fixed length to file with Spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

Spring batch provides FixedLengthTokenizer to read data but I do not see FixedLengthLineAggreator.  How do I write an object into a flat file whereby the different fields should be written into the file with fixed length.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring batch writing to a fixed format file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139496/spring-batch-writing-to-a-fixed-format-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `FormatterLineAggregator`. Just set your fields and set your formats using the [String.format() syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).

```
@Bean
public FormatterLineAggregator<MyObject> myLineAggregator() {
    FormatterLineAggregator<MyObject> lineAggregator = new FormatterLineAggregator<>();
    lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(myBeanWrapperFieldExtractor());
    lineAggregator.setFormat("%-5s%-09d%20s");
    return lineAggregator;
}

@Bean
public BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<MyObject> myBeanWrapperFieldExtractor() {
    BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<MyObject> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<MyObject>();
    fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[]{"fieldOne", "fieldTwo", "fieldThree"});
    return fieldExtractor;
}
```